# SQL Datetime - Specify between times

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime

```
datetime >= dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETUTCDATE()),0)
AND datetime < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,GETUTCDATE()),0)
```

Returns all values for yesterday between 00:00 and 23:00.
I need all values for exactly 2 hours before that, 
From 2 days ago @22:00 until yesterday @21:00

datetime column is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS

Comment: And your question? Something about how to use the functions you are already using, but for hours rather than days? (And a `datetime` does not have a format.)

Answer (score 1):

I got it working, thanks

fyi - Returns all rows from 2 days ago at 22:00, until yesterday at 21:00

```
WHERE
Datetime >= dateadd(hour, 22, dateadd(day,datediff(day,2,CONVERT(datetime, getdate())),0)) 
and datetime <= dateadd(hour, 21, dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,CONVERT(datetime, getdate())),0))
```